# How should I assign a particular subject from a pick list to seperate user?

Tags: admin

for eg: I have a virtual library and have math and science books (Picklist). I make 2 users for math and science separately. now I must get a outcome like math teacher can only see math books.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a two separate profile and assign each one to both the users.
2. Create two record types and 2 page layout and in one record type, enable the science in the picklist value and in other record type, enable the math books subject in the picklist
3. So now If math teachers open that object, he will see the math record type and respective value in the picklist and similarly other science user